# Why netstat lists xinetd IPv6 TCP listen port, but not IPv4 port?

Tags: xinetd

On a Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I installed `xinetd` and `inetutils-telnetd` to serve TELNET clients, and it works well, accepting both clients from IPv6 clients and IPv4 clients.

One thing I notice is: `netstat -ant` lists tcp6 port 23 listen entry, but **not** tcp port 23 listen entry. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPv6 socket listens also on IPv4, as long there isn't a IPv6-only flag set.